# Statement in Database in java

Tags: java, database, jdbc

hi i wrote a servlet and its showing no output
my code is

```
@WebServlet(name="NewServlet", urlPatterns={"/NewServlet"})
public class NewServlet extends HttpServlet {
   Connection connection;
   ResultSet resultset;
   private PreparedStatement updateVotes, totalVotes, results;


    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws ServletException, IOException, ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
        Class.forName( "org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver" );
 connection = DriverManager.getConnection( "jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/HELLOJI","HELLO","HELLO" );
            // TODO output your page here

Statement statement=connection.createStatement();
statement.executeQuery("CREATE TABLE customers(FIRSTNAME char(50),LASTNAME char(50))");
statement.executeQuery("INSERT INTO customer(\"HELLO\",\"HELLO\")");

response.setContentType("text/xml;charset=UTF-8");

        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        try {
            // TODO output your page here
            out.println("<html>");
            out.println("<head>");
            out.println("<title>Servlet NewServlet</title>");  
            out.println("</head>");
            out.println("<body>");
            out.println("<h1>Hehjhkhk</h1>");
            out.println("</body>");
            out.println("</html>");

        }
       finally  {
            out.close();
        }
    } 


    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws ServletException, IOException {
        try {
            processRequest(request, response);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(NewServlet.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(NewServlet.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    } 


    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws ServletException, IOException {
        try {
            processRequest(request, response);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(NewServlet.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(NewServlet.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

            @Override
    public String getServletInfo() {
        return "Short description";
    }// </editor-fold>

}
```

there is no classcast exception or something else.because when i commented statement

```
statement.executeQuery("CREATE TABLE customers(FIRSTNAME char(50),LASTNAME char(50))");
statement.executeQuery("INSERT INTO customer(\"HELLO\",\"HELLO\")");
```

its showing the output .i think the connection with database are perfect the problem is with `statement.executeQuery();` can u please help how to tackle this exception.

Comment: now reduced the code hope someone will help

Comment: Go back and accept some answers too. It's the only thing in Stackoverflow you can do to appreciate somebody's effort and you haven't even done that!

Comment: hi i dont know hw to accept the answer in stackoverflow i also know u helped me alot and appreciate it i wrote the comment below the answer thanks message.please answer the question or tell how to accept answer.but i seriously appreciate stackoverflow effort ad many times discusses its importance in my college seriously great now please answer the question

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation (available at http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeQuery(java.lang.String) executeQuery will throw a SQLException if the SQL statement does not produce a single ResultSet. Try using executeUpdate instead.

Comment: yes now its working fine.but the problem is now when i have to get the data then i have to use executeQuery instead of executeUpdate now its showing no input again.please help hw to remove this sql exception

Answer (score 0):

It might be because of the wrong table name used. customers and customer in two different queries.

Comment: no i corrected it now tablename is customer everywhere but still getting sql exception.i have to create the an android app in 4 days layout is ready i have to connect localhost to the android.please help in solving the issue

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your query with the lines you have commented out. Please try check the following:

(1) Check for typographical errors. `customer` may be `customers` or vice versa, because the table name you have in the two lines are different

(2) Check for the version of your mysql. Usually, the INSERT statement has the form `INSERT INTO <table name> (<fields>) VALUES (<field value>)`.

(3) Try placing the executeQuery lines into a try-catch and print out the exception thrown so you can determine the problem.